# UIWebview not render and only shows html content

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

[ScreenShot.png](https://mildgrind.com/ScreenShot.png)

I use `UIWebview` to load a remote page generated by nodejs.

```
[self.webview loadRequest:request];
```

Page is rendered correctly in the first load, but not rendered and the UIWebview shows weird HTML source code after reload. I tried to change any kind of cache policy, but is still not able to fix it.

Anyone encountered same issue before?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Try it on chrome, safari browser, check if it happens there too

Comment: Browser for desktop is fine. Only not work in mobile mode. I double the responsed page from nodejs behavior differently compared to static .html file.

Comment: ["Be aware that UIWebView is deprecated in iOS 10 - in which case WKWebView is your friend."](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73889)